# Using SelectedItems of TokenLookUpEdit to fill WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, devexpress

i have problem using the values i selected in TokenLookUpEdit to fill datagrid where the invoice number = TokenLookUpEdit selected values

here is my code :

```
   using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection() { ConnectionString = "DataSource='" + DoSomething.Server_Param + "';UserID='" + DoSomething.Uid_Param + "';Password='" + DoSomething.Password_Param + "';Database='" + DoSomething.Database_Param + "';PORT=3306;CHARSET=utf8" })
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()
                {
                    Connection = cn,
                    CommandText = "SELECT InvoiceNumber,ItemCode,ItemName,Items_QTY,Reservation_Date, " +
                    "EngName,UserName,Address,InvoiceStore,ContsrType,Place FROM Delta_Invoices_Grid where InvoiceNumber  ='"+ InvoicesNumbersCombo.Text + "'"
                })
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    InvoicesDetails_Grid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    cn.Close();



                }


                }
```

the problem now is that datagrid is using only one value from TokenLookUpEdit not all selected values and i searched already from yesterday but cannot find a solution

Here is the XAML code for TokenLookUpEdit  and Datagrid :

```
<GroupBox Header="أرقام الفواتير" Margin="76,10,592,439" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontFamily="Droid Arabic Kufi">
            <dxg:LookUpEdit x:Name="InvoicesNumbersCombo" Margin="16,12,16,16"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Delta_Invoices_Grid}"
                                    EditValue="{Binding InvoiceNumber, Mode=OneWay}" AutomationProperties.IsColumnHeader="True"
                                  >
                <dxg:LookUpEdit.StyleSettings>
                    <dxg:TokenLookUpEditStyleSettings />
                </dxg:LookUpEdit.StyleSettings>
            </dxg:LookUpEdit>

        </GroupBox>

        <DataGrid x:Name="InvoicesDetails_Grid" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Dawam_Grid_ItemsBinding}" Margin="460,129,10,243">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#464646" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F0F0F0" />


                </Style>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F88E1D"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFA" />

                </Style>



                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#360E05"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#464646" Offset="0.221"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#4E93CA" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </DataGrid.Background>
            <DataGrid.RowBackground >
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.221"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </DataGrid.RowBackground>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="رقم الفاتورة" x:Name="InvoiceNumber" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding InvoiceNumber}" Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="كود الصنف" x:Name="ItemCode" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ItemCode}" Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="إسم الصنف" x:Name="ItemName" Width="250"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ItemName}" Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="الكمية" x:Name="Items_QTY" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Items_QTY}" Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="تاريخ التركيب" x:Name="Reservation_Date" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Reservation_Date, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}" Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="إسم المهندس" x:Name="EngName" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding EngName}"  Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="إسم البائع" x:Name="UserName" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding UserName}" Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="العنوان" x:Name="Address" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Address}"  Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="المعرض" x:Name="InvoiceStore" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding InvoiceStore}" Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="نوع التركيب" x:Name="ContsrType" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ContsrType}"  Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="مكان التركيب" x:Name="Place" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Place}"  Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="الفني" x:Name="TechName" Width="70" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding TechName}"  Foreground="#F0F0F0"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

and this is the TokenLookUpEdit fill code :

```
InitializeComponent();
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection() { ConnectionString = "DataSource='" + DoSomething.Server_Param + "';UserID='" + DoSomething.Uid_Param + "';Password='" + DoSomething.Password_Param + "';Database='" + DoSomething.Database_Param + "';PORT=3306;CHARSET=utf8" })
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand() { Connection = cn, CommandText = "SELECT InvoiceNumber,CustomerName FROM Delta_Invoices_Grid " })
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);

                    InvoicesNumbersCombo.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    InvoicesNumbersCombo.ValueMember = "CustomerName";
                    InvoicesNumbersCombo.DisplayMember = "InvoiceNumber";


                }
            }
```

Comment: you should show your xaml file....

Comment: Done @Frenchy for both Datagrid and TokenLookUpEdit

Comment: @MohamadSalama can tell me wt is the problem ur facing?

Comment: @Avinash my problem is iam using TokenLookUpEdit and select some invoices numbers and after that press search button which select from MySql database where invoice number = TokenLookUpEdit  selected numbers and fill the Datagrid with the selected rows from database

but untill now cannot use all selected items it brings only one item

Comment: @MohamadSalama from lookupedit u need all the selected values right?

Comment: @Avinash yes  exactly i need to use all the selected values of lookupedit in one Mysql select statment and fill Datagrid with the Result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it another way

first i created public struct

```
 public struct MyData
        {
            public string InvoiceNumber { set; get; }
            public string ItemCode { set; get; }
            public string ItemName { set; get; }
            public string Items_QTY { set; get; }
            public DateTime Reservation_Date { set; get; }
            public string EngName { set; get; }
            public string UserName { set; get; }
            public string Address { set; get; }
            public string InvoiceStore { set; get; }
            public string ContsrType { set; get; }
            public string Place { set; get; }
        }
```

after that i used the add statment throw foreach loop

```
 private void Search_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InvoicesDetails_Grid.Items.Clear();
            foreach (System.Data.DataRowView ZR in InvoicesNumbersCombo.SelectedItems)
            {
                MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection("DataSource='" + DoSomething.Server_Param + "';UserID='" + DoSomething.Uid_Param + "';Password='" + DoSomething.Password_Param + "';Database='" + DoSomething.Database_Param + "';PORT=3306;CHARSET=utf8");
                conn2.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                MySqlDataReader rd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                ds.Clear();
                cmd.Connection = conn2;

                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT InvoiceNumber,ItemCode,ItemName,Items_QTY,Reservation_Date, " +
                        "EngName,UserName,Address,InvoiceStore,ContsrType,Place FROM Delta_Invoices_Grid where InvoiceNumber  ='" + ZR["InvoiceNumber"] + "'";
                rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    InvoicesDetails_Grid.Items.Add(new MyData()
                    {
                        InvoiceNumber = (rd["InvoiceNumber"].ToString()),
                        ItemCode = (rd["ItemCode"].ToString()),
                        ItemName = rd["ItemName"].ToString(),
                        Items_QTY = (rd["Items_QTY"].ToString()),
                        Reservation_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["Reservation_Date"]),
                        EngName = rd["EngName"].ToString(),
                        UserName = rd["UserName"].ToString(),
                        Address = rd["Address"].ToString(),
                        InvoiceStore = rd["InvoiceStore"].ToString(),
                        ContsrType = rd["ContsrType"].ToString(),
                        Place = rd["Place"].ToString()
                    });
                }



                conn2.Close();
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is bind `EditValue` to a collection as you will be getting a list of rows and use a `CollectionConverter` and u need to main the collection changed event of `ObservableCollection` so that u will get a list of selected rows

**Xaml**

```
`EditValue="{Binding SelectedRows, Converter={local:CollectionConverter}}`
```

**Converter**

```
public class CollectionConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter {
        public CollectionConverter() { }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
            return this;
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            return ((ObservableCollection<Object>)value).ToList<object>();
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            return new ObservableCollection<Object>((List<object>)value);
        }

    }
```

**prop**

```
 public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders { get; private set; }
        ObservableCollection<Object> _SelectedRows;
        public ObservableCollection<Object> SelectedRows {
            get { return _SelectedRows; }
            set {
                _SelectedRows.CollectionChanged -= OnSelectedRowsCollectionChanged;
                _SelectedRows.Clear();
                foreach (var item in value)
                    _SelectedRows.Add(item);
                _SelectedRows.CollectionChanged += OnSelectedRowsCollectionChanged;
            }
        }
```

**CTOR**

```
 _SelectedRows = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            _SelectedRows.CollectionChanged += OnSelectedRowsCollectionChanged;
```

**event**

```
 void OnSelectedRowsCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedRows");
```